# Error: ORA-01858 on Executing Query from Laravel

Tags: sql, oracle11g, laravel-5.1

I keep on getting the following error:

```
ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected
```

Whenever I run the following query:

```sql
insert into ZBH_EBUS_CAPPING_INBOUND (group_id, from_date, to_date, amount, period) values (31, TO_DATE('01/01/2015','DD/MM/YYYY'), TO_DATE('01/08/2015','DD/MM/YYYY'), 10.123, 2)
```

When I execute this query directly on SQL Developer it working fine but when I do it though Laravel it fails. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Check your date format 
from DD/MM/YYYY To YYYY/DD/MM